# Does Spring Cloud AWS Secrets Manager config compatible with Spring Boot 2?

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm trying to run spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config with Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEAS version and I have the following error:

```
14:26:59.423 [background-preinit] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.13.Final
14:26:59.430 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
14:26:59.434 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
14:26:59.435 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
14:26:59.436 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
14:26:59.436 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
14:26:59.561 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
14:26:59.565 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
14:26:59.565 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraverseAllTraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
14:26:59.565 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
14:26:59.565 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
14:26:59.565 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
14:26:59.783 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
```

Comment: What version of spring cloud are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb, yes it is. I was answered here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/477#issuecomment-510214608 for that problem. Unfortunately, the documentation is not clear how to use Spring Cloud AWS Secret Manager and there is no working example for it. Thank you for your answer.